# HTML: Push one line to the right when Image is close to two lines of text

Tags: html, image

I have an image next to two sections of text, and am hoping to push first text section (the star rating) to the right, leaving the rest of the text to start next to the photo and continue under the star ratings.

Any tips?
Thanks!

```
<div style="clear: left;">
    <p style="float: left; padding-right: 50px"><img src="https://blog.proven.com/wp-content/uploads/IND.jpg" height="200" width="200" border="1px"></p>
    <p><strong><font size="4">Proven Rating: <font color="#0077b3">★★★★★</p></font></font></strong>
<p>Indeed is a widely used job board with over 200 million visitors a month, in 60 different countries. They post millions of job listings from other job boards, newspaper classifieds, personal ads, and more.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: When asking questions like this, it's best to include a mockup to explain what you want. I'm guessing you want something like the following: https://jsfiddle.net/gppcadb7/ You should really consider getting rid of the `<font>` tags and use CSS.

Comment: That is almost perfect, I would just like sentence to be under the rating instead of wrap around it.  I will look into using CSS for the font, thanks for the help!!